# MongoDB How to add a field to ALL embedded documents in an array

Tags: mongodb, embedded-documents

If I have some documents inside a collection. In this format:

```
{posts: [{"name": "post1"},..., {"name": "postN"}]}
```

What is the equivalent of this function:

```
db.my_collection.update({}, { $set: {"posts.0.lastMod": new Date()}}, false, true)
```

But to update all the embedded documents instead of only position `0`? I have tried doing:

```
db.my_collection.update({}, { $set: {"posts.lastMod": new Date()}}, false, true)
```

But that just gave me an error already on the first document:

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 28,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot create field 'lastMod' in element {posts: [ALL MY ARRAY WAS PRINTED HERE]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the comments above is 99% there.  This makes it a tad safer by ensuring it will only use the dotpath trick to add `lastMod` to an existing array of `posts`.  If `posts` does not exist, without the predicate it will create a *brand new* single object `posts` which is probably not desired.

```
db.foo.updateMany(
    {posts: {$exists:true}},
    [
        { $addFields: { 'posts.lastMod': new ISODate() } }
    ]
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on this documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/, you can add a aggregate pipeline to the 2nd param of updateMany, so you can try this query

db. my_collection.updateMany({},[ { $addFields: { 'posts.lastMod': new Date() } }, { $set: { } }])
because you dont want to add or update any properties else the posts.lastMod, so you can leave the $set as {}

Comment: No, if I put the positional operator as in `posts.$.lastMod` I get: `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.`

Comment: db. my_collection.updateMany({},[
    {
        $addFields: {
            'posts.lastMod': new Date()
        }
    },

     { $set: { modified: "$$NOW"}  }])
     
     plz try this

Comment: This does the trick, but don't really understand why the last `{ $set: { modified: "$$NOW"}}`, this just adds a "modified" field into the document.

Comment: honestly, I just add random fields (in this case modified with timestamp will make more sense) to trigger the updateMany function

Comment: But why would I want to add another field to the document? I just want to add to the subdocuments.

Comment: as I said before, it's just for triggering, you can run 
db. my_collection.updateMany({},[ { $addFields: { 'posts.lastMod': new Date() } }, { $set: { } }])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).